# Is there a way to validate Sabre webservices availability

Tags: sabre

Is there a way to validate Sabre webservices availability without making any webservice method call? Something like HttpResponse check?

Edit - I wanted to validate Webservice's availability and not booking availability. To build a dashboard to monitor the webservice availability (active or down).

Comment: You should probably clarify if you're talking about availability of the webservice (i.e. whether the webservice is down or not) and availability of an itinerary returned by a webservice.

Comment: Thanks you @jcaron. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Given how dynamic availability is, what is available one moment is not necessarily available the next. So the only way to know if an itinerary is still available, is to actually book it.

---

Response to updated question:
There is no specific resource for this, up time should 99% of the time, so I don't think that you would need to validate, the actual call should be enough.

More so, Sabre was recommending using persistent connections as a way to avoid even the handshake.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wanted to validate Webservice's availability and not booking availability. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: There is no specific resource for this, up time should 99% of the time, so I don't think that you would need to validate, the actual call should be enough.

More so, Sabre was recommending using persistent connections as a way to avoid even the handshake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **OTA_PINGRQ** in SOAP for refresh Sabre session and also keep web-service active also.